# How to find missing component for WindowsCE executable

Tags: windows-ce

I have set up an [OpenVPN port](http://ovpnppc.ziggurat29.com/ovpnppc-files.htm) for WindowsCE on my device (CHD Five) with WindowsCE 5.0, but on .exe startup it pops out:

> Cannot find 'ovpncmgr' (or one of its components). Make sure the path and filename are correct and that all the required libraries are avilable.

Same error for main app exe file, but no more error messages, that would allow to understand, where is problem.

The question is, how to debug/find/explore on WinCE what is it, what it is missing, which library/component is missing, like possible in WinXP and other WinOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Depends.exe to look at the dependencies of the application.  It ships with Visual Studio and is also [available for download here](http://dependencywalker.com/).